# How to get the string and added into a list?

Tags: regex, vb.net

The files that are going to load is xml file. after I get to the specific path, which is  I wanted to get the specific string by lines, then added it into a list. 
These are the example of strings that I want to extract from a file. (highlighted from a bold text.

```
<XMLTAG>

<p><b>[1]</b> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum <LINK HREF="test"><i>NAME</i> [2017] 3 ABCD 247</LINK> [1234] 1 ABC 123; [1234] 1 ABC 123:</p>

<p><b>[2]</b> <LINK HREF="test"><i>NAME</i> [2017] 3 ABCD 247</LINK> [1234] 1 ABC 123 lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>


</XMLTAG>
```

I wanted to extract **[1234] 1 ABC 123; [1234] 1 ABC 123** and insert it in the same line as first  in the list.

These are the codes for  extraction.

```
Private Function Slist(ByVal list As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
        Dim rlist As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
        Dim temp As String = ""

        For i As Integer = 0 To list.Count - 1 Step 1
            If i = 0 Then
                temp = list(i).ToString
            ElseIf i = list.Count - 1 Then ' 2nd & before last
                If list(i).ToString.Contains("<i>") Then
                    rlist.Add(temp )
                    temp = list(i).ToString
                    rlist.Add(temp)
                Else
                    temp  = temp & "; " & list(i).ToString
                    rlist.Add(temp)
                End If
            Else 'first 
                If list(i).ToString.Contains("<i>") Then
                    rlist.Add(temp)
                    temp = list(i).ToString
                Else
                    temp = temp & "; " & list(i).ToString
                End If
            End If
        Next
        Return rlist.Distinct.ToList
    End Function
```

I don't know another options on how to extract string after , I came across of using regex, below are the sample of regex pattern I could think of

```
\[\d{4}\]\s\d{1,3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,3}
```

Still, I'm stuck on how to implement it in my codes, anyone can help me on this? Thank you.

Comment: Looks like you want everything that is *outside* a <LINK>...</LINK> block?

Comment: Are you reading this in as a file ?

Comment: yes, but within these pattern of string only `[1234] 1 ABC 123; [1234] 1 ABC 123` @LarsTech

Comment: yes, xml file @MarkHall

Comment: `<\/LINK\>\s+(\[\d+\]\s\d\s\D+\s\d+.\s\[\d+\]\s\d\s\D+\s\d+)`

Comment: This regex only detect 2 patterns, how can I modify if so it will detect any string of pattern i.e `[1234] 1 ABC 123` @Jimi

Comment: Your pattern does! **\[\d{4}\]\s\d{1,3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,3}**

Comment: yes, it will but when I added </LINK> , i.e `\</LINK>;\s` it will only return one pattern, the rest, nope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please consider the following code snippet regarding the Regex which might help you to solve your problem.

```vb
Private Function Slist(ByVal list As List(Of String)) As List(Of String)
    Dim rlist As New List(Of String)
    Dim rx As New System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("\[\d{4}\]\s\d{1,3}\s\w{3}\s\d{1,3}")

    For Each item As String In list
        If rx.IsMatch(item) Then
            rlist.Add(rx.Match(item).Value)
        End If
    Next

    Return rlist.Distinct.ToList
End Function
```

Good luck.

---

**Edit 1**

Let's make things clear. If you prefer the Regx, consider the following:

Suppose that you have the following lines:

```vb
Dim s1 As String = "<p><b>[1]</b> Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum <LINK HREF=""test""><i>NAME</i> [2017] 3 ABCD 247</LINK> [1234] 1 ABC 123; [4567] 2 DEF 456:</p>"

Dim s2 As String = "<p><b>[2]</b> <LINK HREF=""test""><i>NAME</i> [2017] 3 ABCD 247</LINK> [1234] 1 ABC 123 lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</p>"
```

If you Regx the pattern:

```
Dim pat1 As String = "\[\d+\]\s\d\s\D{3}\s\d+"

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(s1, pat1)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(s2, pat1)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

The output will be 3 matches from both strings (s1 and s2):

[1234] 1 ABC 123 
 
[4567] 2 DEF 456 
[1234] 1 ABC 123

Whereas the output of the pattern:

```
Dim pat2 As String = "(\[\d+\]\s\d\s\D{3}\s\d+.\s\[\d+\]\s\d\s\D{3}\s\d+)"

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(s1, pat2)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next

For Each m As Match In Regex.Matches(s2, pat2)
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value)
Next
```

will be just one match from the first string (s1):

[1234] 1 ABC 123; [4567] 2 DEF 456

hope it's clear now, good luck.

Comment: Does this text only consider these string pattern `[1234] 1 ABC 123; [1234] 1 ABC 123` only??

Comment: No mate, It returns **[1234] 1 ABC 123** only or anything in this pattern. ex : **[5426] 3 DAW 323**. I just gave you an example about how to use the Regex using the pattern you mentioned in your question. If I were you, I'd follow @David's answer unless you have entries that contain many <LINK></LINK>.

Comment: does your code detect the pattern after </LINK>? or it detected the any pattern in the files

Comment: I used some of the guidance you teach here, which is declaration of string and the For Each Loop for displaying the data. The text now are displayed according to the regex pattern. Anyway, i store them into a list of string so it is way easy to manipulate the data.

Comment: anyway thanks a lot for your superb explanation! Appreciate it lots @JQSOFT

Comment: Glad to help you mate, and I appreciate your kind support.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is malformed, but Regular Expressions is not required here. You essentially are asking to get all the text after the last occurrence of the keyword `</LINK>`. With that being said, here is a function that does just that:

```
Private Function Slist(ByVal lines() As String) As IEnumerable(Of String)
    Return
        From line As String in lines
        Where line.IndexOf("</LINK>") > -1
        Select line.Substring(line.Substring(line.LastIndexOf("</LINK>") + 8))
End Function
```

You would pass in the lines from your XML file via read all lines, something like the following:

```
Dim _slist As IEnumerable(Of String) = Slist(IO.File.ReadAllLines("your-path-here.xml"))
```

Comment: There is  another text besides these pattern `[1234] 1 ABC 123; [1234] 1 ABC 123`.. The reason I think of regex is because I need to get these pattern but it must be after the </LINK>

Comment: @ari - Could you provide a more accurate representation of your data?